# Bluemix Node js app push Start unsuccessful

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson, clfs

I am using watson conversation service on node js application.

while trying to push application to bluemix. (through command prompt)
After uploading all the files..

0 of 1 instance running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instance running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instance running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instance running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instance running, 1 crashed
FAILED

Start unsuccessful

Kindly help what's the issue..

[command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpvOp.png)

'My coding

```
var watson=require('watson-developer-cloud');

var conversation =watson.conversation({
  url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api',
  username:' ',
  password:' ',
  version:'v1',
  version_date:'2017-06-20'
});
var context={};
context.hour=-1;
function prompt(question,callback){
  var stdin=process.stdin,
  stdout=process.stdout;
  stdin.resume();
  stdout.write(question);
  stdin.once('data',function(data){
    callback(data.toString().trim());
  });
}

function tConvert(time){
  time=time.toString().match(/^([01]\d2[0-3])(:)([0-5]\d)(:[0-5]\d)?$/)||[time];

  if(time.length>1){
    time=time.slice(1);
    time[5]=+time[0]<12?'AM':'PM';
    time[0]=+time[0]%12||12;
  }
  return time.join('');
}
function convMessage(message){
    var d=new Date();
  var n=tConvert(d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ':00');
  context.hour=(n.split(':'))[0];
  context.minute=(n.split(':'))[1];
  conversation.message({
    workspace_id:'09ee7558-0d3e-4af3-8429-14e60be348d7',
    input:{'text':message},
    context:context
  },function(err,response){
      if(err){
        console.log('error:',err);
      }else {
          console.log('Watson: ' + response.output.text[0])
          prompt('You: ', function(input){
            convMessage(input);
          });
          context=response.context;
        }
      });
    }
convMessage('Hi.');
```

Comment: Likely your code has a problem. You need to share it with the deployment logs.

Comment: Code running successfully in local. Log page is loading....loading.. but not showing anything

Comment: Do you use the VCAP-provided PORT?

Comment: no I am not using VCAP port. I have posted my coding now. Thanks for your kind reply Henrik..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program might run locally. However, to run as Bluemix Node.js app on Cloud Foundry it needs to meet certain requirement. A web app is expected and the health manager checks on the expected port whether your app is alive. If the app cannot be detected it is considered "dead" and the logs will show it as "crashed".

Take a look at the sample app "[Conversation Simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple)" and the [main file "server.js"](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/server.js) for how the port info is handled.

As an alternative for your code, you could consider setting a [health check type](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#health-check-type) of `process`. It would indicate Bluemix / Cloud Foundry that you don't deploy a regular (Web) app, but something running in the background or executed once.

Comment: Thank you Henrik.  Now I am using git hub code.I understood what I have missed.

Comment: In app.js once i changed the line from 

if (!workspace || workspace === '<workspace-id>') { 


to


if (!workspace || workspace !== '<workspace-id>') {



it's working fine now